# VBA dictionary with custom type containing array

Tags: excel, vba, dictionary

Asked a question before but I was maybe a bit unclear. So I was recommended to use Dictionaries to search for items. But I cant wrap my head around on how to use it with an array. My object class looks like this:

```
Private index As Integer
Private id As String
Private nameID() As Variant
Private data() As Variant
Private cnt As Integer

Public Sub init(value As Integer)
    index = 0
    cnt = value
    id = ""
    ReDim nameID(0 To cnt)
    ReDim data(0 To cnt)
End Sub

Property Let setID(value As String)
    id = value
End Property

Property Let setName(value As String)
    nameID(index) = value
End Property
Property Let setNameArray(value As Variant)
    nameID = value
End Property

Property Let setData(value As String)
    data(index) = value
    index = index + 1
End Property
```

So I want to import this to a dictionary so I can search for specific keys or `nameID's` in this case. Both nameID and data are arrays that contains my id and it's value. Is there a way to do this in dictionary or can I just import it?

Illustration:

[image]

Comment: It's unclear to me what exactly you're trying to do.

Comment: @igorsp7 Added an image that (hopefully) explains it a little better

Comment: A dictionary allows to retrieve an item very quickly by key and it enforces uniqueness of the keys. If you're creating a data structure like this (which is probably a bad idea to start with), you can use a dictionary in every "ObjectClass", or you can implement a search algorithm from your root "Array". I would probably recommend revisiting the need to for such a data structure.

Comment: I'm not sure that I can do it any other way. Problem is that each objectclass is an individual file that is later on stored together into the array. I'm thinking of replacing the objectclass but would I be able to search the branches of the tree then?